# Terminology - DMZ

Tags: terminology, dmz

The term DMZ is used to describe a separation area between a trusted zone and an untrusted zone. Ex: internal network vs internet.
**Can it be used to refer to a separation area between a trusted zone and a less trusted zone.**? 
For instance,in mail architectures, we often have a mail gateway in a DMZ and an internal mail server in an isolated network that connects for instance to a domain controller.
 **Can the isolated network that hosts the internal mail server be called a DMZ?**

Answer (score 1):

DMZ has its own detailed meaning which is [fully described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29).  It implies a machine that receives all external traffic that is not already linked to an internal request to the predetermined DMZ controller.

Many people simply use DMZ as a means of bypassing the main router's firewall but it can be used to implement a more advanced firewall.

To answer your highlighted question directly, DMZ can indeed be applied at any and multiple levels of networking.  So yes there could be a DMZ in the internal network between a `trusted zone and a less trusted zone` but that is not typically needed in most networks, as the router is usually sufficient to handle this.

Comment: Please don't confuse the true meaning of a network DMZ with the bastardized meaning touted by consumer home router manufacturers. While they could be considered *related*, they are most definitely *not the same*.